# Average video frame size for video codec

Tags: video

In simple words, is it true that an average size of an encoded video frame would be `FrameSize = BitRate/FrameRate`? Because `BitRate` shows how much data we are transferring per time unit, and `FrameRate` shows how many frames does this time unit contain.

Answer (score 1):

No.

That method will generally yield very erroneous (low) results.

Video codecs generally do a LOT of compression on the video stream, as part of encoding the video.  The bit rate is of the bits AFTER encoding.

Comment: so how the average frame size can be calculated? why we can't use bitrate if it shows the bits after encoding - what we want actually...

Comment: It's calculated in the same way any other average is calculated.  You do equally spaced measurements over time, and then average them together.

Comment: This is going to vary wildly in real content, depending on where the key frames are and what the content is like.

Comment: @StevenBurnap does this mean that video codec does not quarantee constant values for bitrate and/or framerate? Or maybe i'm getting these definitions wrong?

Comment: No, a video codec does not always guarantee constant framerates or bitrates for video. H.264, for instance, will prioritize between the two by adjusting the keyframe interval as well as the update interval. it will not exceed a certain bitrate nor a certain framerate, but a specification for one can limit the other, while generous limits on both with a video feed that doesn't change much can result in fewer frames and bits than the spec allows.

Comment: I watched "Mission Impossible 2" in a good digital theater.  The action scenes near the end were GORGEOUSLY choreographed.  Not long after that, I saw it, on DVD, with a good projector and a cheap DVD player.  The action scenes were BUTCHERED, because the slow codecs SIMPLY COULD NOT KEEP UP with the highly-dynamic source video.  For some applications, there is no substitute for bandwidth.

Comment: Good example, thank you However, how should one understand a bitrate in terms of video coding?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, I suppose technically you're correct if you're looking for a general average. But I think we'd really have to hear the use case that you're looking for, as I can't imagine the resulting value being useful for very much at all (in fact, I mostly agree with John's answer). Each frame's size is going to vary wildly; random example. The 20th frame of a person looking at the camera is going to take up about 12 KB, whereas the jump-cut to a helicopter shot of Hong Kong's skyline is going to take up 700 KB.

Just a general tip for this site; often, giving more details about the exact problem you're trying to solve (ie, *"My videos are streaming very slowly, and so I'm trying to...."*) may get you more helpful results than a very direct question.

Comment: There is no actually certain problem. I was thinking about encoded video transmission over the network and trying to understand/derive the average number of bytes coming through the channel per time unit and whether it is possible to give an estimate of that in terms of average frames size if one could be defined...